# Jpa not flushing delete

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have following code:

```
@Transactional
public class DbCrudServiceImpl implements DbCrudService {

    @Override
    public void cleanupDb() {
        ...
        serviceUserRepository.deleteAll(); //Spring data JPA repository for entity ServiceUser
        serviceUserRepository.flush();
        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

which is a Spring bean.

I set `hibernate.show_sql` to `true` in Jpa properties and logger of `org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener` to `DEBUG` in order to inspect what's happening in cleanupDb.

Shown cleanupDb's lines produced log:

```
23:18:53.398 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:149 - ## Processing flush-time cascades
23:18:53.401 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:189 - ## Dirty checking collections
23:18:53.406 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:123 - ## Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 8 objects
23:18:53.407 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:130 - ## Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 24 collections
Hibernate: select ... from SERVICE_USER ...
23:19:01.753 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:149 - ## Processing flush-time cascades
23:19:01.757 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:189 - ## Dirty checking collections
23:19:01.761 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:123 - ## Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 8 objects
23:19:01.763 [main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener:130 - ## Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 24 collections
```

Why there is no delete statement?
Why wasn't it flushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because Hibernate walks the entire object graph and if the parent hasn't been deleted, it canceled the child delete.

You can check this by changing you log level to TRACE and look for the following message from Hibernate:

un-scheduling entity deletion